# Apache Nifi: Is there a limit on the output produced by the ExecuteStreamCommand Processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I am running into a strange issue and just want to rule out a possibility by asking this question.

I am executing Java code via this processor, the processor works fine on certain command-line arguments but on others the output is blank. However, when I run the exact same command in the host terminal window the output is fine. The output that's written to the STDOUT is about 1 MB.

My question is, is there a limit on the size of the data that this processor can write to STDOUT, the output flow file?

I am on NiFi 1.9.1

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the property "Output Destination Attribute" then the output is put in a flow file attribute and is limited by the value of "Max Attribute Length" with default of 256 characters.

If you are not putting the output in an attribute, then there is no limit.

Comment: Thank you Bryan, I am not putting the output in an attribute, so "unlimited" is the answer.